# Enable Integration Services on a remote server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am attempting to deploy an SSIS package on a remote SQL Server by following the [following tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9069/deploy-and-schedule-an-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-package-step-by-step/). My issue is that the Integration Services Catalogs folder is empty and when I try to create a catalogue, I get the following error:

> The path to the catalog backup file could not be determined.
> Integration Services might not be installed on this server, or the user may not have the appropriate access permissions

Is it even possible to achieve my goal on a remote server or do I absolutely need access to the machine on which it is running on?

Answer (score 0):

Once SSIS is installed on the server, you can create the SSIS catalog and deploy SSIS projects to the catalog remotely.